# Obtain html content from pdf url (Jsoup)

Tags: java, html, pdf, jsoup

I'm making a software which is supposed to retrieve the title of a webpage from a provided url and tried JSoup to achieve that.
The links are mostly from youtube and JSoup works perfectly with them, but occasionally an input will be in the form of a pdf like so: http://www.ninsheetmusic.org/download/pdf/2066
That's when i get the following exception:

```
org.jsoup.UnsupportedMimeTypeException: Unhandled content type. Must be text/*, application/xml, or application/xhtml+xml. Mimetype=application/pdf, URL=http://www.ninsheetmusic.org/download/pdf/2066
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:689)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection$Response.execute(HttpConnection.java:628)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.execute(HttpConnection.java:260)
at org.jsoup.helper.HttpConnection.get(HttpConnection.java:249)
at core.Request.parseTitle(Request.java:54)
at core.Request.<init>(Request.java:29)
at core.GrakeBot.parseRequest(GrakeBot.java:161)
at core.GrakeBot.onMessage(GrakeBot.java:59)
at org.jibble.pircbot.PircBot.handleLine(PircBot.java:990)
at org.jibble.pircbot.InputThread.run(InputThread.java:92)
```

Now i take it JSoup doesn't handle pdf, but is there anything i could do here to avoid this exception and get the webpage title?

This is the code i'm using right now:

```
private String parseTitle(String link)
{
    Document doc = null;
    String title = "Title could not be retrieved";

    if (getType() == RequestType.YOUTUBE)
    {
        try
        {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(getLink()).get();
            title = doc.getElementById("eow-title").text();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return title;
    }
    else if (getType() == RequestType.SHEET)
    {
        try
        {
            doc = Jsoup.connect(getLink()).get();
            title = doc.getElementsByTag("title").text();
        } catch (IOException e)
        {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return title;
    }
    else
        return title;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can't use JSoup for this. This is not HTML. I looked at the source and the data you receive back looks something like this:
`%PDF-1.5
%Çì¢
5 0 obj
<</Length 6 0 R/Filter /FlateDecode>>
stream
xœÍ\]\[³$GqÆö1áë˜à…GœQUf\]ý†    Làp8¿¬xÀ+åÐ
„1?ÉÿÒy©KöîYítŸÌîÃ™¯«ºº.™YyëêßœÜÕÃÉñÿþãå«‡÷œO¿üâ!~÷à®Îa©%Qá“?üƒ‡„pŠ Ã5åÓ+E.#£O~ò s5ýñù/~óP®Èÿä‚ýýòÕé? Ç—“Ï×RNü‚:Pk
 åþTü5”SJpÍpúàÕÃùk—þë!Ôk§þ…áwèÞœ¨·ñÑÃùëRéZJ8=&¹·_ŽW úS}óÒ\[j¾årÙ<í-•‘&3õ"8éóªwïnÀM-\]¡ä=¾ìÚ­béýMô¦èû<üè&rñÙYzQh\]ª¦\¡)ÙÙr…¦<Ù&t›*~>‘«Hq¬Ù78‹cÝ+œÅ›b…£8”h‹Åh‹Å¾$\[Üà,eS¬p{¿)V8Š\]ÞLKƒÂªïZ=bÞäef\[÷£Ï4¸$ÏO1Òo”YŒDG£´üò!æ:Ð§)&ªçåžÈ÷D'“£-ƒ×{~ñ÷ú¨Ñ\[y×ôGAö7=`...

You'll have to parse it with a library. After looking, it looks like Apache PDFBox is what you want. This code is from the documentation and untested but it looks like what you want to do:

```
PDDocument doc = PDDocument.load("http://www.ninsheetmusic.org/download/pdf/2066");
PDDocumentInformation info = doc.getDocumentInformation();
String title = info.getTitle();
```

The only thing left is to install Apache PDFBox :)

Comment: *"it looks like Apache PDFBox is what you want"* - Strictly speaking Apache PDFBox is just *one of many* PDF libraries the OP can use for this task...

Comment: I feel like adding Apache PDFBox is not really optimal for my goal.
I might be saying something really stupid here, correct me if i'm wrong:
By opening the aforementioned link in firefox and opening the Page Inspector i find there is some html code and in fact there is a <title> tag. (where else would firefox get the text to show the page title?)
Is there any way to access that html code with jsoup and retrieve the title from there?

Comment: @RamzahBeoulve you could open a plain socket connection, then parse that with JSoup.